# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens causes WebAPI to return 401 Unauthorized, against IdentityServer4

Tags: .net, authentication, authorization, identityserver4

I have IdentityServer4 as identity provider and token issuer in microserve architecture along with other WebAPIs. 
Today all of sudden I couldn't get authorized to my API project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a fiew hours of debugging I realized that the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` was causing all the trouble. I had it installed on a Shared library project couple of days ago. When I removed it everything came back to normal.